# UIAction sheet for sharing and sending

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I know there are options to customize UIActionSheet, but I notice many app's "share/send" options all look similar to this:

[image: send/share]

Is there some sort of template that makes this or something like this more automatically than creating all one's own buttons etc to try to mimic this? I tried to look through the docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIActionSheet.html) and searching SO but didn't find anything. Can someone point me to the well-known and obvious sdk functions I would use to create this sort of sharing action sheet? Thanks a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is this "UIActivityViewController", introduced in iOS 6, provides a unified services interface for sharing and performing actions on data within an application.

Apple's Doc is here: [UIActivityViewController - Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/)

**NSHipster's tutorial is even better**: [UIActivityViewController - NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/)

Answer (score 0):

This is an UIActivityViewController. Google can help you to implement it.